# Navigation drawer with MPAndroidChart not working

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I am using MPAndroidChart to display some data. I am showing different charts on different menu option. Each menu option calls a fragment. Pie Chart displays fine but the Navigation toggle is not working. I don't get any error in LogCat.

[image]

Below is the code.

**Pie Chart fragment XML**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:id="@+id/mainLayout">



 <com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.PieChart
        android:id="@+id/chartPie"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**PieChartActivity.java**

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    try {

        root = (RelativeLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_piechart, container, false);

        getActivity().setContentView(R.layout.fragment_piechart);
        mainLayout = (RelativeLayout) root.findViewById(
                R.id.mainLayout);
        mChart = (PieChart) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.chartPie);
        // add pie chart to main layout
         //mainLayout.addView(mChart); 
        //mainLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#55656C"));

        // configure pie chart
        mChart.setUsePercentValues(true);
        mChart.setDescription("OEE composition");

        // enable hole and configure
        mChart.setDrawHoleEnabled(true);
        //mChart.setHoleColor(Color.BLACK); 
        mChart.setHoleRadius(7);
        mChart.setTransparentCircleRadius(10);

        // enable rotation of the chart by touch
        mChart.setRotationAngle(0);
        mChart.setRotationEnabled(true);

        // set a chart value selected listener
        mChart.setOnChartValueSelectedListener(new OnChartValueSelectedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onValueSelected(Entry e, int dataSetIndex,
                    Highlight h) {
                // display msg when value selected
                if (e == null)
                    return;

                Toast.makeText(PieChartActivity.this.getActivity(),
                        xData[e.getXIndex()] + " = " + e.getVal() + "%",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected() {

            }
        });

        // customize legends
        Legend l = mChart.getLegend();
        l.setPosition(LegendPosition.RIGHT_OF_CHART);
        l.setXEntrySpace(7);
        l.setYEntrySpace(5);

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Log.d("Error", ex.getMessage());
    }

    // Quality
    makeHTTPCall(objGlobal, "574c22cd7625423b05a2cbcc",
            prod_Count_UBI_link_QLTY);

    // Performance
    makeHTTPCall(objGlobal, "574c22ad76254239d6a6bc56",
            prod_Count_UBI_link_PERF);

    // Availability
    makeHTTPCall(objGlobal, "574c1e027625420f0e4401ff",
            prod_Count_UBI_link_AVAIL);

    return root;

}
```

**PieChartActivity extends Fragment**

```
 public class PieChartActivity extends Fragment implements
        OnChartValueSelectedListener
```

Interestingly navigation toggle is working fine with other charts on different fragments.

Let me know if any more details are needed.
I am new to Android, tell me if i m wrong at any basics...

Comment: Sorry for elaboration, but only swipe gesture doesn't work or toggle in action bar, too?

Comment: Both don't work...

Comment: Can you post the complete `Fragment` code

Comment: cant share all the code :( it has link to cloud which i cant share..

Comment: Can you paste your activity code please?

Comment: and where is the `DrawerLayout` ??

Answer (score 1):

Place your pie chart layout in @layout/app_bar_index activity.

Comment: I'm upvoting your post so that you can grow your reps soon and give these kind of answers in comments.. Okay?